# Save Mongodb aggregation results on multiple id field in a new collection

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have to aggregate some data in mongodb through the java driver, and save the aggregation result in a new collection, and later print this collection in a Jtable; the id field can be not simple in my case (i can't know if it is a single value or not) so I followed this:
[How to write multiple group by id fields in Mongodb java driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15564562/how-to-write-multiple-group-by-id-fields-in-mongodb-java-driver)

when I want to save the result in a new collection, doing this:

```
for (DBObject result : output.results()) {
        report.insert(result);
    }
```

i have this error:
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: fields stored in the db can't have . in them. (Bad Key: 'store.address.store_state')

this is a piece of the collection where I do the aggregation:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("549ef5d17c8db9efa75d49c9"),
"store" : {
  "store_id" : NumberLong(2),
  "store_type" : "Small Grocery",
  "region_id" : NumberLong(78),
  "store_name" : "Store 2",
  "store_number" : NumberLong(2),
  "address" : {
    "store_street_address" : "5203 Catanzaro Way",
    "store_city" : "Bellingham",
    "store_state" : "WA",
    "store_postal_code" : "55555",
    "store_country" : "USA",
    "store_manager" : "Smith"
  },
  .....}
```

Can anyone help me?

Note: ID Field can be simple (only a field) or complex (two or more fields)
The new collection I want to create must have all the fields that compose the ID in the aggregation, and all the fields result by aggregation. That's beacause I had to print that collection in this way: [Retrieve data from MongoDB collection into Swing JTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26616072/retrieve-data-from-mongodb-collection-into-swing-jtable)

for example:

```
DBObject fields = new BasicDBObject("unit_sales", 1);
            fields.put("store.store_type", 1);
            fields.put("store.store_name", 1);
            fields.put("store.address.store_city", 1);
            fields.put("_id", 0);
            DBObject project = new BasicDBObject("$project", fields );

 Map<String, Object> dbObjIdMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            dbObjIdMap.put("store_type", "$store.store_type");
            dbObjIdMap.put("store_name", "$store.store_name");
            dbObjIdMap.put("store_city", "$store.address.store_city");
            DBObject groupFields = new BasicDBObject( "_id", dbObjIdMap);

            groupFields.put("average", new BasicDBObject("$avg", "$unit_sales"));
            DBObject group = new BasicDBObject("$group", groupFields);

AggregationOutput output = collection.aggregate(project, group);
```

So i want as result a table with column store_type,store_name, store_city, average.

I know I'm exposing my problem here so bad, but i'm not english and i don't speak very well the language, so please try to understand me.. sorry

Comment: The error clearly says that the field names in the document you try to persist to mongoDB cannot have `.` in them. Can you print and update your post to reflect the document that you are trying to insert in `report.insert(..)`.

Comment: Could you add your request?

Comment: sorry, I add the request now